# Bitwise Integer Conversion

Tags: c++

I have to use an API that returns int32_t. But the actual value might be of a smaller signed/unsigned type. To Know the the exact type the API returns ENUM values. It looks something like this:

```
typedef enum Int{
    Int8,
    Int16,
    Int32,
    Uint8,
    Uint16,
    Uint32
}IntT;

typedef struct{
    IntT (*getType)();
    void (*getInt)(int32_t* out);

}IntegerT;
```

I want to convert the value from int32_t to the actual type by knowing the enum value. Sometimes I even want to assign for example an unsigned int32 to an unsigned int64 variable in my code. Knowing that the unsigned int32 is returned as int32_t if the value is big enough then it is represented as a negative value in in this type and if I just static_cast it to uint64_t then the sign bit is extended to fill all the the higher bits in uint64_t which yields a totally different unsigned value than that is intended.

Therefore, I have written a cast function that should take care of casting to a bigger int type or a smaller int type to the correct value. However, I feel that this might be a known issue and there might be an already existing solution. Below is the function. Please inform if you think this can be improved or if there is a better solution (I have made this function a bit more generic than I really need for my usecase though).

EDIT: Made this portable with regards to Endianness.

EDIT: Removed compiler warnings about signed/unsigned comparisons.

```
#include <limits>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp> //BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/type_traits/make_unsigned.hpp>


namespace Detail
{
/** This a implementation helper class for bitwise_int_cast function */
template<bool IsToTypeSigned, bool IsFromTypeSigned>
class Converter
{
public:
    template<typename ToIntType, typename FromIntType>
    ToIntType convert(FromIntType from) {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(from) == 0); //This prevents this generic implementation being compiled
        return from;
    }
};

/** From signed to signed */
template<>
template<typename ToIntType, typename FromIntType>
ToIntType Converter<true, true>::convert(FromIntType from)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::is_signed && std::numeric_limits<FromIntType>::is_signed);
    if((from < std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::min()) ||
            (from > std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::max())
      ) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Integer overflow in casting from large signed rvalue into smaller signed lvalue");
    }
    return static_cast<ToIntType>(from);
}

/** From signed to unsigned */
template<>
template<typename ToIntType, typename FromIntType>
ToIntType Converter<false, true>::convert(FromIntType from)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::is_signed && std::numeric_limits<FromIntType>::is_signed);
   typedef typename boost::make_unsigned<FromIntType>::type unsignedType;
   unsignedType unsignedIn = from;

   if(std::numeric_limits<FromIntType>::digits < std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::digits) {
       if(from < 0) {
           return unsignedIn;
       }
    } else {
        if(from > 0) {
            if (unsignedIn > std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::max()) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Integer overflow in casting from large signed rvalue into smaller unsigned lvalue");
            }
        } else if (from < 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Integer overflow in casting from large signed rvalue into smaller unsigned lvalue");
        }
    }
    return unsignedIn;
}

/** From unsigned to signed */
template<>
template<typename ToIntType, typename FromIntType>
ToIntType Converter<true, false>::convert(FromIntType from)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::is_signed && !std::numeric_limits<FromIntType>::is_signed);
    if(std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::digits < std::numeric_limits<FromIntType>::digits) {
        typename boost::make_unsigned<ToIntType>::type allBitsSet = -1; //e.g. 0xFFFF
        if( from > allBitsSet) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Integer overflow in casting from large unsigned rvalue into smaller signed lvalue");
        }
    }
    return static_cast<ToIntType>(from);
}

/** From unsigned to unsigned */
template<>
template<typename ToIntType, typename FromIntType>
ToIntType Converter<false, false>::convert(FromIntType from)
{

    if(from > std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::max()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Integer overflow in casting from large unsigned rvalue into smaller unsigned lvalue");
    }
    return static_cast<ToIntType>(from);
}


}


/**
 * This cast only cares about integer sizes not sign mismatch
 * works only on two's complement (Big or Little Endian) Machines
 */
template<typename ToIntType, typename FromIntType>
inline ToIntType bitwise_int_cast(FromIntType from)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::is_integer && std::numeric_limits<FromIntType>::is_integer);
    Detail::Converter<std::numeric_limits<ToIntType>::is_signed, std::numeric_limits<FromIntType>::is_signed> converter;
    return converter.template convert<ToIntType>(from);
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you're working with a library that returns _all_ integers as `int32_t`s? Including _unsigned_, 32-bit integers? I've never seen something like that.

Comment: Yes it is true and unfortunate

Answer (score 2):

You can use an union:

```
union mergeint_t
{
  int8_t int8;
  int16_t int16;
  int32_t int32;
  int64_t int64;
  //..
};
```

Assign the value to int32:

```
  mergeval.int32=yourFunctionReturningInt32();
```

And then access the value from appropriate member of the union.

```
if (type==INT8_T) {
  int8val = mergeint.int8;
}
```

//EDIT:

I tested this method, because I was uncertain whether the byte order would be properly kept here. On my Linux the program below works OK:

```
int main() {
  union mergeint_t mergeval;
  mergeval.int64=11;
  printf("mergeval int8=[%d]\n\n", mergeval.int8);
}
```

Giving output: `mergeval int8=[11]`

//EDIT2:

Yes, this method may not work on Big Endian machines. I don't have one, so I can't test it. Sorry for not mentioning it before. I thought that if I mentioned byte order in my doubts above, it would be more or less clear that it's a possibly limited solution.

Comment: Sorry, I get confused. Did you mean that the return type of API should be union? because I see in the if clause you are using the union as rvalue(as if it is returned from the API). If this is the case I can not use this because I can't change the API.

Comment: Furthurmore this is not safe as someone can assign a large value to int64 and get use int8.

Comment: Writing to one value of the enum and reading another will render UB because of illegal type aliasing, except for the `int8_t/uint8_t` cases. Moreover, that will surely fail in big endian machines.

Comment: @rodrigo I am not certain about the UB. `struct { uint16_t val16; uint8_t val8[2]; }` is a pretty common sight. Could you provide source?

Comment: @amirmonshi I edited the code. The assignment is now also included. In general, you always assign the return value to `int32` and then get the value from the union based on the returned variable type.

Comment: @Dariusz Thanks for clarification. But I still think that this is a an unsafe casting. For instance if there is a bug in the API or the usage of this pattern. That is when the actual assigned value exceeds the boundaries of the target type. That is why I've added all those bound checkings. However, if you add those checks (for example by wrapping the union and enum in class) and do safe conversions it might become an elegant solution. The problem that Rodrigo mentioned is real. I didn't think about it and as you can see I have used union conversion in my solution(so my solution is not correct)

Comment: @Darius,@rodrigo The problem is because obviously union members point to the same memory address(this is not the case for structs). In little endian machines pointers to variables point to the least significant byte. Therefore when you write value 1 to int8_t member it is written to the least significant byte of int16_t member which yields also value 1. But the problem is in Big Endians where the value one is written to most significant byte of int16_t member and the value becomes 256! (I experimented with this today on a Solaris machine)